# Difference between two malloc definition of a struct

Tags: c, compiler-construction, casting, malloc

I would like to know if there's a real difference between this:

```
c = (struct_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct_t));
```

and this

```
c = malloc(sizeof(struct_t *));
```

Besides avoid the cast, is the compiler takes any advantage in the second form respect the first? Or the two ways are completely the same and is just a *"aesthetical"* question ?

Comment: hmmm... I have a `typedef struct struct_t { .... } struct_t;`

and I declare `struct_t * c;`

Comment: ahhh okok. You're right. Probably the second form could be:
`c = malloc(sizeof(*c));`. Isn't it?

Comment: @Kyrol Use `c = malloc(sizeof(struct_t));` and forget about the other cases, they likely don't make sense for what you are attempting to do.

Comment: So I have just to avoid the cast. Right? But are you sure that if I declare c as a pointer, your form is correct? I'd like to know why is correct. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first allocates `sizeof(struct_t)` bytes, the second `sizeof(struct_t*)` bytes.

Apart from that, there is no difference in what `malloc` does, whether you cast the result or not. Casting the result makes the code acceptable to C++ compilers, but it can hide the mistake of not including `stdlib.h`, therefore it is widely preferred to not cast the result in C.

Comment: So, for this reason, is better if I use the first or the second?

Comment: Well, you have to use the correct size. Then, if you have that, I prefer the version without cast, since the cast is unnecessary (and can hide errors if you don't compile strictly to a standard that forbids implicit declarations). C++ people often prefer the one with the cast.

Comment: C++ people should use `new`, compile C code with a C compiler, and link it to their C++ project...

Comment: ... and malloc isn't the only reason to compile C code with a C compiler rather than a C++ compiler.

Comment: I'm not using C++, just C.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue The new reigning opinion among C++ people is that they shouldn't even use `new`, if my impressions do not mislead me. I strongly agree that C code should be compiled with a C compiler.

Comment: @DanielFischer Has a concept only slightly different to C#'s `stackalloc` been adopted in C++, which promises some degree of "compatibility"?

Answer (score 5):

**The two are totally different.** The first allocates an *instance* of the struct, whereas the second allocates a *pointer* to the struct.

In general, they won't even allocate the same number of bytes.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same. The latter allocates 4 or 8 bytes of space for a pointer to struct, the first allocates enough space for the struct it self.

When sizeof(struct_t) is small enough, and when the malloc allocates actually more than requested, the user may not see the difference.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I always used the first form, but recently I saw also the second form and I wanted to understand if there was any big differences. Thanks.

Comment: Only rarely there's need to allocate space for a _single_ pointer. It's more like the interface needs to be redesigned.

Answer (score 1):

Two forms are different. They both allocate memory, but with different amounts.
General rule is as follows:
when allocating type T, the result of malloc shall be casted to T*.

```
void sample1()
{
    struct pollfd *pfd = (struct pollfd*)malloc(sizeof(struct pollfd));
    // pfd is points to a memory with a size of struct pollfd
    ...
    free(pfd);
}

void sample2()
{
    struct pollfd *pfd = (struct pollfd*)malloc(sizeof(*pfd));
    // same as above, but uses variable type instead
    free(pfd);
}
```

If you specify incorrect type in malloc argument, generally that will lead to buffer overrun problems:

```
void sample3()
{
    struct x *px= (struct x*)malloc(sizeof(struct x*));
    x->field = 5; //<< error, as allocated only 4 or 8 bytes depending on pointer size
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are different.

Usually malloc returns (void*). So you want to typecast void* to (struct_t*).

Comment: no you must never typecast a malloc in c , [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1)

Comment: But i used to typecast all of my program. It works without any error or crash, Why?

Comment: This is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1), to your question , if you have the time/patience , go and have a look there , but i have no time/patience to explain to you an answer , which is clearly explained in the link i sent.

Comment: thanks Mr.Barath Bushan. i cleared with the link which you sent.

Comment: no problem , just correct your answer about typecasting malloc